# How to upgrade existing project scaffolded with Yeoman

Tags: yeoman

I used generator-angular a few months ago to scaffold a project and the whole ecosystem (karma, Node versions, grunt packages) has moved on quite significantly. I keep running into problems running tests, building things, and so on.

I know I can use nvm to downgrade my Node version and install older packages, but that kind of  sucks, especially when there are many developers on the team. I have used the generators for 10+ projects over the past few months so I'm very interested in a solution.

Is there a recommended upgrade path for when new versions of generators are released, apart from just regenerating the project and copying files across?

(Just to note: this isn't a problem with upgrading a Yeoman 0.9 project.)

Comment: Have you tried running `npm update -g` for global packages and `npm update` for local packages in the project directories?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

First make sure you have committed everything or have a backup, then just scaffold out over the project again. `yo` will ask you for each file if you want to overwrite. For those files you haven't edited, just say yes. For the other ones, type `d` for diff and see what's changed. Then manually do the changes, and run `npm install & bower install` to get the latest dependencies.

### EDIT

As mentionned in comments by Markus Gattol :

> yo `<generator-name>` now already run `bower install` & `npm install` i.e. no need to run them explicitly again – Markus Gattol

Comment: Great answer! I didn't know it was smart enough to do the diff for me. Good to get authoritative answers from authoritative sources.

Comment: `yo <generator-name>` now already run `bower install & npm install` i.e. no need to run them explicitly again

Comment: @MarkusGattol don't know why but `bower install` always fails for me on all machines. I keep run it explicitly again.

Comment: @Sumit this is because if bower isn't given root level permission all commands without a `--allow-root` will not run!