# How to update generated files by yeoman?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've generated my project with generator-gulp-webapp and I can see that this generator was updated since then.

Is there any way to update gulpfile.js, etc, without generating project from scratch?

Comment: Did you find a solution using yeoman ? I also search this feature

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade existing project scaffolded with Yeoman](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480316/how-to-upgrade-existing-project-scaffolded-with-yeoman)

Comment: I just flagged your question to an answered one. I think it is the best way to achieve that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18500003/3197383

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to update the gulpfile.js only would be to go into your local storage of the updated, latest generator your using and pull down the raw file.

For me it sits in this location on my PC

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\generator-gulp-webapp\app\templates\gulpfile.js

Or pull the latest file directly from github

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp/blob/master/app/templates/gulpfile.js